# How to display extra columns (created by, created date , version) for my wiki page inside the default EnterPriseWiki page layout

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, page-layout, publishing-site, aspx

I am working on an EnterpriseWiki site collection, and I want to add extra fields to the default enterprisewiki.aspx page layout which are (Created By, Created date & Version fields). So I did the following steps:-

- I open the SharePoint designer.
- Inside the page layout, I edit the EnterpriseWiki.aspx page layout.
- From the right side toolbox, I drag the “Document Created By” & “Document Modified By” fields and drop them inside the page layout, as follow:-

[image]

But I am facing these problems:-

1. The displayed values for these two columns will include the domain name as follow; “`0#.w|ad-CompnayName\test.user`”. so is there a way to extract the username only and delete the “.” . So the final field result will have value such as `“Test User”` instead of `“0#.w|ad-CompnayName\test.user”`.
2. The “Document Modified By” field will not show the final user who has modified the page, not sure what this field will display?
3. Is there a way to make the `SharePoint:TextField` inside the page layout to be read-only or disabled, so users can not insert values inside them. i column mark-up is:-
4. If I want to display the page version & Created Date which fields I should drag-drop ? as I cannot find any of these columns inside the right toolbox in the sharepoint designer, that reference the page version or created date ?

Can anyone advice ?

Comment: 1,3 use jquery.

Comment: @XristosK can you adivce more on this ? and what about the other points?